# popUp appearing on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

Asp.net, Using a Jquery popUp when a button is clicked on the page works fine. However the popUp appears for a brief second on the inital load of the page and I can't seem to see why. Is it css? is it some attribute im not setting?
any advice helpful ta.

Answer (score 1):

Since the HTML of popup is not hidden on page load, it flashes for a second and then it is hidden by Javascript/jQuery library/plugin using the popup common class.

Hide the popup by CSS.

```
.myPopup {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

some javascript is loading your popup disable it with a css code.

css is loaded first in loading of page. you need to find the popup class and disable showing.

```
.myPopup {
    display: none;
}
```